# LibGDX - is it possible to specify fullscreen resolution?

Tags: java, libgdx

As stated [here](https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3870), `graphics.setDisplayMode(int width, int height, boolean fullscreen)` was replaced by two new methods, `graphics.setWindowedMode(int width, int height)` and `graphics.setFullscreenMode(DisplayMode mode)`

`DisplayMode` has protected constructor, so is there any way to explicitly specify fullscreen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out.

```
Monitor primary = Gdx.graphics.getPrimaryMonitor(); 
DisplayMode[] modes = Gdx.graphics.getDisplayModes(primary);
```

`modes` now contains all possible resolutions which could also be used in fullscreen.